# ¿Cómo acceder al contenido de una variable Shape en VBA de Corel Draw?

Tags: vba, javascript-objeto

Mi objetivo es crear una Macro para Corel Draw que renombre las páginas de un **`.CDR`** buscando determinada palabra en todos los textos de la página y reemplazando el nombre de la página por las 3 palabras siguientes a esa. Le pedí ayuda al CHAT GPT pero el código que me brinda no funciona.

Al debugguear el error está en que trata de comparar `Shape.Text.Story.Text` con un *String* y no coinciden los tipos de variables.

No logro encontrar como acceder al contenido del texto de una variable *Shape* para guardarlo en un *string* y compararlo o utilizarlo.

Probé con `Shape.Text.Story.String` pero me muestra:

> variable de objeto o bloque with no establecido

No se si soy claro con lo que necesito. Agradezco cualquier indicación.